# How to enqueue second stylesheet in Wordpress child theme?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I'm using a child theme and need to enqueue the stylesheet for a slider. The css file is located in a folder in the parent theme directory, i.e. `/parent-theme/css/flexislider.css`

I created the child theme using a plugin which added a `functions.php` file to the child theme directory with the following code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',array('parent-style')
);
}
```

I assume I have to add another entry to the above function referencing `flexislider.css` but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPDATED

Based on what you added to the question, you should be able to just add to that function and register the stylesheet. The full function would look like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',array('parent-style')
);
wp_enqueue_style('flex-slider',get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexislider.css');
}
```

I don't have much experience with child-themes, but following the model in that function, I think `get_template_directory` points to the parent theme and not the child theme, which you said the flexislider code is located

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm still not quite sure how to do this. I just updated my question with some more details which might help you be more specific with your answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to incorporate your updated question

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would work too, but it doesn't. You said, "...and register the stylesheet". Do I need to also register the stylesheet? Is that done separately?

Comment: Sorry, I made a formatting error with the code and the slider is displaying correctly now. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Awesome! Good luck with the site. Please accept this answer if it helped with your issue.